# Serializer for Value which holds Set<String> in redis

Tags: java, serialization, redis, set

I have to store Set as value in my redis. I am not able to figure out how to serialize it and set in the below object

```
RedisTemplate<String,Set<String>> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Set<String>>();
redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(NEED_A_HASH_VALUE_SERIALIZER_HERE);
redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(NEED_A_VALUE_SERIALIZER_HERE);
```

Need some help here

Answer (score 0):

You can use lpush or rpush in redis to push your strings into an array in redis and retrive it using the following method.

```
List<String> result = cacheClient.getLRange("FRE_TRIG_WL", 0, -1);
HashSet<String> wl = new HashSet<String>(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this

```
new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(Set.class, String.class))
```